# showing combobox item from database

Tags: c#, combobox

I want to show the data into combobox from database.
I became successful to show that but my first data of the database cant be shown in the combobox.
My used code is :

```
 con.Open();
        SqlCeCommand cmnd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmnd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM register_for_combobox";          
        SqlCeDataReader rd = cmnd.ExecuteReader();

            while (rd.Read())
            {
                string registerd_dpt = rd[0].ToString();
                string registerd_semestr = rd[1].ToString();
                string registerd_crs = rd[2].ToString();
                string registerd_tcr = rd[3].ToString();

                dpt_comboBox.Items.Add(registerd_dpt);
                semester_comboBox.Items.Add(registerd_semestr);
                course_combobox.Items.Add(registerd_crs);
                teacher_comboBox.Items.Add(registerd_tcr);                   
            }
```

My code is working well except i cant show the first data of the database onto the combobox.
What is wrong here??
I cant understand.
Can anyone help me??

Comment: I dont quite understand... What data is not being displayed?  What do you mean by `first data`  the first record in the database?

Comment: Why are you not using Dataset. I would suggest not using the reader.  Create a dataset and dataadapter and set the datasource of the combobox = dataset.  From there you can set the display member and value member.

Comment: first record in the database is not being displayed . @paqogomez

Comment: what is the problem of my current code?? Why the first record is not being showed??? @Anna.P

Comment: did you debug through the code? see actually the record you want is retrieved from the db.

Comment: yeah.the whole record except the first one is being showed in the combobox @Rezoan

Comment: i say, just debug line by line and see data you want is mapped to the string variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you figured out your problem yet?

In trying to duplicate this i ran the following code against a table i know has 3 records and all 3 showed up in the combo box:

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=xxxxx;Initial Catalog=yyyyy;Integrated Security=true;");
        SqlCommand cmnd = con.CreateCommand();

        cmnd.CommandText = "Select * from BillingType";

        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader rd = cmnd.ExecuteReader();

        while (rd.Read())
            {
                string someFieldText = rd[1].ToString();

                comboBox1.Items.Add(someFieldText);
            }
        }
        con.Close();
```